# Как задать размер шрифта разом для всех элементов страницы WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в Settings сборки хранятся параметры размера шрифта. Отдельно для кнопок и отдельно для всего остального текста. Я создал стиль в ресурсах юзерконтрола

```html
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" 
          Value="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ButtonFontSize}" />
</Style>
```

и таким образом задал размер шрифта для всех кнопок.

Но кроме этого у меня есть еще меню, гриды, разные опции, в общем, еще много элементов, для которых тоже нужно задать шрифт. Можно ли разом задать для них всех размер шрифта и, если да, то как?

Comment: Попробуйте `TargetType="{x:Type Control}"`. Если нет, то сделайте этот стиль как базовый, что то вроде `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="BaseStyle">` и дальше от него наследуйте все стили - `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />` / `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />` итд.

Comment: Ошибка "Type Control is not supported in a WPF project". Пробовал ставить UserControl - то же самое.
Но в любом случае ваш вариант предполагает выставление для каждого типа контрола стилей вручную, то есть сначала для кнопки, судя по ответу, потом для метки. Это я могу сделать, но мне хотелось бы разом для всех сразу. Так сказать, если для элемента в принципе можно задать размер шрифта, я хочу это сделать разом, а не возиться с заданием для каждого типа отдельно.

Comment: Что вы делали, что бы такое получить? Вот я [попробовал](https://hastebin.com/dojinogupe.xml) с Lable и успешно изменил шрифт у всех Lable элементов. Единственная проблема - это может к TextBlock не стилям не наследоваться базовый, решается созданием еще одного базового стиля, но только с типом `TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"`

Comment: Ничего особенного, просто вставил в ресурсы еще один тег
<Style TargetType="x:Type Control">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Font}" />
        </Style>
и разметка сломалась с этой ошибкой.

Но я не про это. Для каждого типа контроллов по-отдельности я знаю как сделать. А мне нужно чтобы разом для всех, грубо говоря что-то такое:
<Style TargetType="AllControls">...</Style>
и у меня сразу и чекбоксы, и label, и гриды и все остальное получает заданный размер шрифта.

Comment: `разметка сломалась с этой ошибкой` - посмотрите как у меня задается `TargetType` и как у вас.  `разом для всех` - на сколько я знаю, нельзя так сделать. Вам придется писать что то вроде [этого](https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/develop/Source/Fasetto.Word/Styles/Fonts.xaml), где пропишете каждый нужный тип.

Comment: Точно, скобки пропустил, спасибо.
Эх, печально, что нельзя для всех разом конечно.

Comment: Один из вариантов - задать параметры шрифта самому окну (`<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">`). Тогда почти все элементы окна будут по умолчанию иметь такой размер шрифта.

Answer (score 1):

Вот таким образом можно задать размер шрифта для всего, что будет объявлено в ресурсах

**SettingsProvider.cs**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class SettingsProvider
    {
        public double FontSize
        {
            get { return Settings.Default.ButtonFontSize; }
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Theme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Resources/Theme.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    d1p1:Ignorable="d">

    <local:SettingsProvider x:Key="SettingsProviderKey" d:IsDataSource="True" />

    <Style x:Key="CommonControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource SettingsProviderKey}, Path=FontSize}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="CommonTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource SettingsProviderKey}, Path=FontSize}" />
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```